# importing a big standard contract

Tags: solidity, evm

I am following a tutorial to use oracle from Provable, so I have to import "https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/blob/master/provableAPI_0.6.sol". I notice that the contract is very big but all I need is the function `provable_query`. A big imported contract make the deployment consume more gas, right? Is it a good practice to delete things unrelated to the desired function `provable_query` before deployment?

Comment: Have you checked what function `provable_query` needs inside this contract?

Comment: I haven't checked in details but I am pretty sure I can still leave out a lot of code and `provable_query` would still work. I wanted to ask in general whether it would make a different in gas usage to justify the hassle.